# Issue with jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript

I have initialized the accordion in the following way.

```
<script>
$(function()
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight:false});
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine except the below content is not moving down when expanding a section which contains more height than the first one.

The url to see it in live is http://thephpcode.com/index.php/web/setting_issue

Try to expand the last section and see the button below accordion in not moving down. It appears on top of the accordion display. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this **plugin**: http://accordion-cd.blogspot.com/

If you want by default particular item selected.
There are also many options available to customize your requirement.

**Parameter to pass in plugin:**

```
heading  :  null  //mandatory to provide Heading tag to attach event
content  :  null  //mandatory to provide Content to show/hide
headingEvent  : "click"   //Attach Event
active : 0   //By default visible element
callapsAll  :  false   //to hide all on page load
expandAll  :  "expandAll"   //Element name on Expand All Functionality attached
collapsAll  :   "collapsAll"   //Element name on Collapse All Functionality attached
headingClass  :  "accordion-header"   //Accordion Heading Class
contentClass  :  "accordion-content"   //Accordion Content Class
```